# Working with an external button box

Tags: visual-studio

I tried this question on Stack Overflow, but I was pointed here, so here goes:

For a new project for myself, I am looking for a way to be able to (for example) open a pop-up window on my laptop, by pressing a button on an external device (to be build by myself, or at least bought) connected with USB.

Basically I would be looking at something like a Arduino or Raspberry (IF I am looking in the right direction) with buttons on it, and as soon as I hit a button on the external box with physical buttons, a command activates on my laptop and for example opens a popup window in which I can input tekst.

Does anyone know:
1) if it is possible to do this at all.
2) What equipment is needed for the external box, what programming is needed. I preffer .net (dot net) but maybe it can only be done with software from the external box.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, like make/model of the external box or websites I would be very happy.

I have knowledge of Visual Studio/.net but I am willing to learn other languages if .net is not an option for this project.

Thanks in advance

Scott

PS: If anyone knows of some better tags, or at least knows what I mean and needs me to edit the question, please do tell me... I am new on Stack Overflow/Superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement your external box as a USB HID device, that way you don't have to write any drivers. Your box will essentially pretend to be a keyboard, providing certain keys that your other keyboard doesn't. You can then setup keybindings for these keys.

I know the Arduino platform has software to make it easy to construct a fake keyboard like this. I believe Python and C++ are the preferred languages for this. .NET is poorly supported on Linux, so you probably don't want to use that.

Comment: Thank you wingedsubmariner! At least now I know I could use the Arduino platform :) But I am solely working on Windows. I want each button on the fake keyboard to represend a different customer and the key will open a pop-up box, in which I can insert text.

Comment: @Scott You should look into [AutoHotKey](https://http://www.autohotkey.com/). This will allow you to make keypresses cause custom events, like launching a program. And .NET is a great choice for custom Windows programs.

Comment: Is it possible to map this to an Arduino device? If so the answer is there :)

Comment: @Scott Basically the Arduino box pretends to be a keyboard, Windows listens to the Arduino box and generates keypress events, AutoHotKey intercepts those and runs your .NET program, and your .NET program opens the appropriate dialog. Its a lot of steps, but most of the work is already done for you in each of them.

Comment: I don't care really for the amount of steps... It is fun to learn :) But it is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! (Don't have enough rep to do anything nice)

Comment: @Scott Don't worry about the rep Scott, having fun with your project!